# Cocoa: hide NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I'm using UIXOverlayController to show custom popup in my application.

Popup has some buttons, one of them is "Send SMS" which uses MFMessageComposeViewController.

When i click "Send SMS" button, sms composer appears, but without it's TOP bar (where "Cancel" button is located).

Suppose, that my application's Navigation Bar overlaps SMS composer Bar and i need to bring sms top bar to front.

I also tried to hide navigation bar when popup window is active, but there is no method "self.navigationBar" in overlayController ".m" file. And i think that all work with hide/show navbar should been done in overlaycontroller.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `self.navigationBar.hidden = YES;`? That should hide the navigation bar.

Comment: I tried to add  self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES; but it doesn't work. If i add it in any other ViewController - it works OK. But in overlay controller it doesn't works (may be it doesn't have access to "parent" navigation bar?